# "Decorating" a String in Java with position-based characters

Tags: java, text

I have a text string, and a list of position-pairs that define spans in the text that I need to "decorate" (or annotate). For examle:

```
String t1 = "I saw Bob, and also Mary, John's sister.";
int[][] pos1 = {{6, 9}, {20, 39}, {26, 30}};
```

Expected output:

```
"I saw [Bob], and also [Mary, [John]'s sister]."
```

The important points are:

1. The positions refer to the **original** text. So after adding the first '[', the rest of the positions become invalid and must be manually updated.
2. The spans may overlap (like "John" and "Mary, John's sister"). So after adding a '[', updating the other positions is not trivial.

I guess I can implement these updates, but it seems to be pretty complicated, with a lot of index bookkeeping and edge cases. Is there any existing class that performs this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For working double bracket.

String t1 = "I saw Bob, and also Mary, John's sister.";

int[][] pos1 = { { 6, 9 }, { 20, 39 }, { 26, 30 }, {26, 30 } };

result "I saw [Bob], and also [Mary, [[John]]'s sister]."

```
public class Record implements Comparable<Record> {
    private int index;
    private String value;

    public Record(int index, String value) {
        this.index = index;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Record o) {
        return index - o.index;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String t1 = "I saw Bob, and also Mary, John's sister.";
        int[][] pos1 = { { 6, 9 }, { 20, 39 }, { 26, 30 }, { 26, 30 } };

        List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < pos1.length; i++) {
            records.add(new Record(pos1[i][0], "["));
            records.add(new Record(pos1[i][1], "]"));
        }

        Collections.sort(records);

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int firstIndex = 0;
        for (Record r : records) {
            result.append(t1.substring(firstIndex, r.getIndex())).append(
                    r.getValue());
            firstIndex = r.getIndex();
        }
        result.append(t1.substring(firstIndex));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String t1 = "I saw Bob, and also Mary, John's sister.";
    int[][] pos1 = {{6, 9}, {20, 39}, {26, 30}};

    Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i=0; i<pos1.length; i++) {
        map.put(pos1[i][0], "[");
        map.put(pos1[i][1], "]");
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int firstIndex=0;
    for (int i: map.keySet()) {
        result.append(t1.substring(firstIndex, i)).append(map.get(i));
        firstIndex = i;
    }
    result.append(t1.substring(firstIndex));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Careful, those indexes change each time you append them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - there is still room for some optmization but the general idea is here. I think it is quite readable.

```
private String getDecorator(int charIndex, int[][] pos) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
        if (pos[i][0] == charIndex) {
            return "[";
        }
        if (pos[i][1] == charIndex) {
            return "]";
        }
    }
    return "";
}

public String decorate(String text, int[][] pos) {
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (int charIndex=0; charIndex < text.length(); charIndex++) {
        sb.append(getDecorator(charIndex, pos));
        sb.append(text.charAt(charIndex));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```